# "You don't have permission to view or edit anything." even if user has access to model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

**SOLVED**

---

I know this "error" message is common and there are already posts around this. But did not find a way to fix my issue.

I am using the already existing "User", "Group", "UserManager" provided by Django. However, I have a custom authentication backend:

```
    class MyAuthentication:
       # ...
       # ...
       def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
       permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=user_obj)
       if perm in permissions:
           return True
       return False
```

My user is an admin NOT a super user. He is part of a group which has all the permissions to view, edit, delete, add my models.

**He is able to access them** by using the URL directly.

However, when he tries to connect to the admin page `/admin/`, he is getting this error message.
`You don't have permission to view or edit anything`

I searched for a permission which will give him access to view the lists of models in django documentation, but found nothing.

Do I need to add anything to my backend authentication? Add a new perm ? Even advice on where to look at in order to investigate would be very appreciated!

### EDIT1

After debugging the django code itself, I need to add this method:

`def has_module_perms(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):`

So stupid error ...

Answer (score 2):

I needed to change my has_perm, because permissions is a QuerySet of Permission...

In case anyone needs it, here is my working has_perm method and fixed code to check both groups perms and user's perms.

```
def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
    permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=user_obj).values()
    has_specific_perm = False

    # Check groups permissions the user is member of
    for group in user_obj.groups.all():
        has_specific_perm = self.check_has_permission(perm, group.permissions.all().values())

    # Check user's permissions if group was not enough
    if not has_specific_perm:
        has_specific_perm = self.check_has_permission(perm, permissions.values())

    if user_obj.is_active and user_obj.is_staff and has_specific_perm:
        return True
    return False

def has_module_perms(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
    return True

def check_has_permission(self, perm, permissions_to_check):
    for index in range(len(permissions_to_check)):
        if perm == permissions_to_check[index]['codename']:
            return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using django v3.2.15 and this is my answer based on WilliamW's answer, in my case it works properly.
thanks for answer from WilliamW.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    if self.is_superuser:
        return True
    elif self.is_staff:
        has_specific_perm = False

        # Check groups permissions the user is member of
        for group in self.groups.all():
            current_permissions = [
                f'{ContentType.objects.get(pk=itm["content_type_id"]).app_label.lower()}.{itm["codename"]}'
                for itm in group.permissions.values('codename', 'content_type_id')
            ]
            has_specific_perm = self.check_has_permission(perm, current_permissions)

        # Check user's permissions if group was not enough
        if not has_specific_perm:
            current_permissions = [
                f'{ContentType.objects.get(pk=itm["content_type_id"]).app_label.lower()}.{itm["codename"]}'
                for itm in Permission.objects.filter(user=self).values('codename', 'content_type_id')
            ]
            if current_permissions:
                has_specific_perm = self.check_has_permission(perm, current_permissions)

        if self.is_active and self.is_staff and has_specific_perm:
            return True

    return False

def check_has_permission(self, perm: str, permissions_to_check: list):
    if perm in permissions_to_check:
        return True
```